# call a function with every two consecutive variables

Tags: r

I've got

```
c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

and I'd like to call the function `foo()` with

```
foo('a', 'b')
foo('b', 'c')
foo('c', 'd')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From #R@irc.freenode.org:

```
x<-letters[1:10]; mapply(function(y,z) paste(y,z), head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
```

Comment: You might also find the function `embed` helpful in more general situations.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty 'for' loop to do the job:

```
foo <- function(a, b) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
}

a <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

for (i in 1:(length(a)-1)) {
  foo(a[i], a[i+1])
}
```